# How can I display 'Latin subscript capital letters' in PyQt?

Tags: python, unicode, pyqt, subscript

I'm using Python for my GUI Application(using PyQt4), and I want to use 'Latin subscript capital letters' in my GUI tableWidget. PyQt4 supports Unicode, so I succeeded in displaying the Unicode characters in the GUI, such as: 'Latin subscript small letters' - U+2090.., 'Subscript Digits' - U+2080.., 'Superscript Digits' - U+2070.., etc.

But I cannot find 'Latin subscript capital letters' in the Unicode character set.

The exact character I need is ['K with Latin subscript capital letter S and E'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxO2O.png).

MS Word displays this character successfully using a numerical expression. How can I display this character in Python?

Comment: There are no subscript capital letters in Unicode.

Comment: Oops... I see. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Word probably defines markup to display subscripts, similar to the HTML code `K<sub>SE</sub>` → *K<sub>SE</sub>*. Unless your QT widget accepts some markup language for the displayed text I think you're out of luck here.

*U+01D6A8* is actually *MATHEMATICAL BOLD CAPITAL ALPHA*, not subscript.

Comment: Oh, yes. U+1D6A8 is not subscript, it is my mistake. i edit this now! Thanks.

Comment: @Rizamong Anyway, programs normally don't use Unicode characters to display subscripts and superscripts in mathematical expressions, they use markup.

Comment: There are several Qt widgets that will render a [limited subset of HTML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/richtext-html-subset.html) - for instance, `QLabel`. So `<sub>` tags is definitely the way to go on this.

Comment: @roeland Thank you i use QLabel widget to express HTML with  `K<sub>SE</sub>`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks! i use QLabel widget into Qtablewidget cell with `setCellWidget` method. it display correctly `K<sub>SE</sub>`.